# Why is retrieving data from Elasticsearch so much faster than from PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, performance, postgresql, elasticsearch, offset

Doing the following simple database lookup with a database index on the timestamp field "created" takes 10x longer than doing the same lookup on an Elasticsearch index (holding the same data):

```
SELECT * FROM "my_table" ORDER BY "created" DESC LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 200000
```

There are no filter, no text search in this query - it's a simple lookup with a **high offset**. Using lower offsets yields equally fast results for PostgreSQL and Elasticsearch. The larger the offset, the bigger the time difference. And Even without ordering the results, using a large offset takes much, much longer than with ES.

Is that normal or could there be an option in PostgreSQL that is not set right? In general, the database performs very well and it's used on a high traffic website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The larger the offset, the more rows the server needs to compute, so the query will get less efficient the higher the offset used.

The [Postgres doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-limit.html) for `limit/offset` warns:

> The rows skipped by an OFFSET clause still have to be computed inside
>   the server; therefore a large OFFSET might be inefficient.

What does the query plan look like for a small `OFFSET` versus a large one?

Depending on the exact use -- say if you're doing backend work on the server -- you may be able to use a *cursor* instead of doing a series of `SELECT`s with `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`, although for user-facing things and other stateless-connection scenarios -- i.e. pagination -- that's probably not an option.

Comment: That's a thorough explanation - thanks! So, there's no flag to set or anything? It's for a Django application and this is the query Django's paginator uses by default. It seems to more efficient to stick with Elasticsearch for such operations then.

Comment: Sure, no problem. There's no flag specifically for this, but it's possible you may be able to tune your *Postgres* server's config to perform better overall. See [this link](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization) for more info.

Comment: If you want to have fast pagination with PostgreSQL then you need to use a value as your offset e.g. ``created > '2015-06-09'``. That is, provide the latest value that you show on each page as the condition for the next.

Comment: A deeper `where` clause could certainly help mitigate the issue that occurs with large offsets by making the possible set smaller, but to ensure proper pagination you'd still need to use `offset` and `limit` to ensure you get, say, 50 items per page. (Based on date, there could be 50 or 500, and so on.)